# Doesn't the equation $T = 273.16* P/P_\text{tr}$ become equal to infinity as $P_\text{tr}$ approaches zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature

I came across this equation  $T = 273.16\, \mathrm{K}\, P/P_\text{tr}$ , where $P_\text{tr}$ is the pressure at the triple point of water and goes to zero, and $P$ is the pressure at temperature $T$.

What I don't understand is that if $P_\text{tr}$ goes to zero, wouldn't it make the whole equation equal to infinity?

Comment: The pressure at the triple point can't go to zero.  For each substance, it is a specific value.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's a specific value. However, the equation is defined through lim $p_tr$ -> 0

Comment: This means that the gas behaves like ideal gas

Comment: Without any context to where you saw this equation it will be harder for people to answer you, just saying you came across an equation doesn't help much.

Comment: No real substance has a triple point pressure of zero, so such an infinity can't happen in the real world.

Comment: @Alisa Would that not be the basis of a short answer ?

Comment: @Triatticus well, it is in the syllabus of an exam. It just says "State and use the equation"... so there isn't much context I can provide

Answer (score 1):

This is just [Gay-Lussac's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay-Lussac%27s_law), which states if the volume is constant then the pressure and temperature are related by:

$$ \frac{P_1}{T_1} = \frac{P_2}{T_2} $$

or with a minor rearrangement:

$$ T_2 = T_1 \frac{P_2}{P_1} $$

In this case the temperature $T_1$ and pressure $P_1$ are being taken as the values at the [triple point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point) of water:

$$\begin{align}
T_1 &= 273.16~\textrm{K} \\
P_1 &= 611.66~\textrm{Pa}
\end{align}$$

so in your equation $P_{tr}$ is the constant $611.66~\textrm{Pa}$. For some reason the temperature at the triple point has had its numerical value substituted rather than being written as $T_{tr}$.

So $P_{tr}$ cannot go to zero since it is a constant.

Comment: Well, this is what I don't understand... this equation is in a syllabus of an exam and the only thing it says is "State and use the equation $T=273.16*P/P_tr$ , where $P_tr$ is the pressure at the triple point of water and goes to zero, and P is the pressure at temperature T"  ... perhaps they didn't word it correctly?

Comment: @Alisa there must me a misprint because that sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the reply!